# Setting up SSL / Need to Setup Mail first

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to set up SSL and I got a certificate from Comodo but they sent an email to hostmaster@mysite.org and unfortunately I don't have the inbox set up. Postfix is installed (Ubuntu 16.04) and when I send mails through PHP mail() it works fine, but I now need to receive mail. I am ok with CL/Bash for lots of other stuff but have got "confused" with this one as I need to get it sorted for a project very soon. Virtual Server on Virtualmin.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask them to send it to your WHOIS contact email address or do a text file or CNAME based verification ( this one should work for you )